# Swift - Complex Regular Expression on Password Field

Tags: ios, regex, swift, expression, jpasswordfield

**I need a password regex that contains at least a capital letter, small letter, digit, special character and that is between 8 to 30 characters long. How can I do that?**

Currently I have this code below which does not work correctly.

```
let passwordRegex = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&#])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*?&#]{8,30}"
```

Comment: Add a `$` at the end. However, the problem might be in your code if you are using the pattern in a method that anchors the pattern by default. Are you using it inside NSPredicate?

Comment: Great thanks @grundic